# canvas text looks blurry on images in android

Tags: android, canvas

When drawing the text though, it gets blurred and not that crisp like when using below code. The only code I've used for the text painting on image can some one help me to solve this issue

### code

```
 public static Bitmap drawMultilineTextToBitmap(Context gContext, Bitmap bitmap, String gText) {
        // prepare canvas
        Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
        // set default bitmap config if none
        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        // so we need to convert it to mutable one
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG|Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setTextSize(10);
        int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * scale);
        // init StaticLayout for text
        StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(gText, paint,
                canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                false);
        // get height of multiline text
        int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();
        // get position of text's top left corner
        float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth);
        float y = (bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight);
        // draw text to the Canvas Left
        canvas.save();
        //canvas.translate(x, y);
        canvas.translate((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (textLayout.getWidth() / 2), y);
        textLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

### image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess here:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

should be false. And two more methods which may relate to this issue:

```
paint.setAntiAlias(false);
paint.setFilterBitmap(false);
paint.setDither(true);
```

Comment: @Krish I updated my answer. There are two more methods which may relate to this issue. Hope it works.

Comment: Can we add background color for StaticLayout?